# jqGrid soap error - Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '_' (code 95) in prolog; expected '<'

Tags: jquery, soap, jqgrid

I implemented simple SOAP web services. The request and response XML are successfully transferred with soapUI.

== Request XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aaa="http://www.aaa.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aaa:getMember/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

== Response XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getMemberResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.aaa.com">
         <return>
            <user>
               <id>aupres</id>
               <passwd>aaa</passwd>
               <age>45</age>
               <name>husband</name>
            </user>
            <user>
               <id>hwa5383</id>
               <passwd>bbb</passwd>
               <age>40</age>
               <name>wife</name>
            </user>
            <user>
               <id>julian</id>
               <passwd>ccc</passwd>
               <age>15</age>
               <name>son</name>
            </user>
         </return>
      </ns2:getMemberResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I try to call the response soap XML with jqGrid script like belows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery SOAP test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="grid.locale-kr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var soapMessage = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " + 
            "xmlns:aaa=\"http://www.aaa.com\"> " +
            "<soapenv:Header/> " +
            "<soapenv:Body> " +
            "<aaa:getMember/> " +
            "</soapenv:Body> " +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>"

   var $Grid = $("#grid");
   $Grid.jqGrid({
      mtype: "post",
      url: "CallMemberBean",
      datatype: "xml",
      datastr: soapMessage,
      processData: false,

      xmlReader : {
         root : "return" 
      },
     colNames : [
        'id',
        'password',
        'age',
        'name'
     ],
     colModel : [
        { name : 'id',        width:40,  align:'center', xmlmap:'id'},
        { name : 'passwd',    width:80,  align:'left',  xmlmap:'passwd'},
        { name : 'age',       width:80,  align:'left',  xmlmap:'age'},
        { name : 'name',      width:80,  align:'right', xmlmap:'name' }
     ],
     pager : '#pager',
     rowNum : '10',

     loadComplete : onloadComplete,

     loadError : onloadError,

     gridComplete : ongridComplete
      });

      function onloadComplete(data) {
     console.log(data)
      }

      function onloadError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(jqXHR)
     console.log(errorThrown)
         console.log(textStatus)
          }
    });
```

This jqGrid client codes throw the following error

```
20:45:52,568 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-45) Interceptor for {http://www.aaa.com}CallMemberBeanService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:259)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final.jar:2.3.1.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '_' (code 95) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2052)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1157)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:161)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: Sorry, but why one should use steam motor now? I mean: why you implemented **soap web services**. It's retro technology, which is practically dropped now. It's better to use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for example. In general the usage of XML from web services is retro style. One uses JSON mostly. Typically you need just return object and it will be serialized to SOAP/XML/JSON by .NET. Thus you will don't need to write any special code at all, you need just use more modern underlying .NET components.

Comment: The error message which you posted looks like *server side error*. You use `datatype: "xml"` and the data will be loaded from `url: "CallMemberBean"`. To use `datastr: soapMessage` instead of making request to `url` you need to use `datatype: "xmlstring"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed **datatype** to **xmlstring** as you told me. Then no exception was thrown. But **console.log(data)** of **function onloadComplete(data)** threw the input message **soapMessage** , not response. The soap web services did not work.

Comment: You don't described in the question what you wanted to implement. Either you need to lead the data from the `url` or you want to load the data from `soapMessage` (you used `datastr: soapMessage`). The `datatype` should corresponds your choice. If you need to use some message as **request message** then you should use `postData: soapMessage`

Comment: I want to get some response soap message from the request **soapMessage**. I am totally confused why my input soap message is displayed on **console.log(data)** of **function onloadComplete(data)**.  **$.ajax({  url: "CallMemberBean", type: "POST", datatype: "xml", processData: false, data: soapMessage, contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8", success: function (data) {
console.log(data) },**  works successfully and bring the sopa response.. Pls, inform me. Thanks..

Comment: What JavaScript code you used now? (`datatype` and other jqGrid options)

Comment: It is solved. These are soap configuration, 
         mtype: "post", url: "CallMemberBean",
         datatype: "xml",
         datastr: soapMessage,
         processData: true,
         postData:soapMessage,          Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message, which you posted looks like **server side error**. You use `datatype: "xml"` and the data will be loaded from `url: "CallMemberBean"`. To use `datastr: soapMessage` as **the input data of the grid** instead of making request to `url` you need to use `datatype: "xmlstring"`.

If the `soapMessage` contains the **Request XML**, then you should use `postData` parameter instead of `datastr` parameter:

```
postData: soapMessage
```

If the type of `postData` parameter is the string, like in your case, then the value of `postData` **replace** the standard parameter, which send jqGrid typically. You should probably add `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8" }` option additionally.

One more way to send **custom formatted data** to the server is the usage of `serializeGridData` callback function. The data, which returns the callback, will be used as the data used by underlying jQuery.ajax request. It allows you to build SOAP request which contains some dynamic options (the current page number, the page size and so on):

```
serializeGridData: function (postdata) {
    return soapMessage; // can be build from postdata dynamically
}
```